# Rest Api documentation with swagger and Spring MVC

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, swagger, springfox

Hi' I have several REST api in my spring mvc project and I would like to create documentation for each service and store it in file so I can share with the team.
I often read about Swagger or Springfox and  configure it so, I added

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
    <version>2.2.2</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
    <version>2.7.0-rc1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
    <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

and config class:

```
package com.config.core;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

import springfox.documentation.builders.RequestHandlerSelectors;
import springfox.documentation.service.ApiInfo;
import springfox.documentation.spi.DocumentationType;
import springfox.documentation.spring.web.plugins.Docket;
import springfox.documentation.swagger2.annotations.EnableSwagger2;
import static springfox.documentation.builders.PathSelectors.*;
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig {

    @Bean
    public Docket api(){
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.any())
            .paths(regex("/api/.*"))
            .build()
            .apiInfo(apiInfo());
    }

    private ApiInfo apiInfo() {
        ApiInfo apiInfo = new ApiInfo(
            "My Project's REST API",
            "1.0",
            "This is a description of your API.",
            "API TOS",
            "me@wherever.com",
            "API License",
            "API License URL"
        );
        return apiInfo;
    }
}
```

but swagger-ui.html doesn't exist, I have :

```
> /v2/api-docs 
> /configuration/security
> /configuration/ui 
> /swagger-resources
```

So, how can I see my web server documentation and save it on file? I would like to avoid to show on url when users have to use the web platform.Thanks

Comment: Did you use the swagger annotations in your endpoints.

Comment: I added '@Api' and '@ApiOperation' one of my controller, but swagger-ui.html return 404

Comment: Try http://localhost:port/yourapp/swagger/index.html

Answer (score 0):

springfox-swagger-ui is a webjar and the resources embedded in the jar need to be registered via resource handlers.

You need to add the resource handlers [as demonstrated in the spring mvc demo](https://github.com/springfox/springfox-demos/blob/master/spring-java-swagger/src/main/java/springfoxdemo/java/swagger/SpringConfig.java). That way the swagger ui assets can be rendered by the application.